# Sending emails from excel in outlook no longer works

Tags: excel, excel-formula, outlook, outlook-addin

Before I go asking for help I want to let you know that I am not very good at this and have just learnt bits and bobs from online pages and forums when coding.

I've got a spreadsheet which I set up for sending out for quotations to certain suppliers (repetitive). I have been using this spreadsheet for almost 2 years now and it's been working fine. Late last week I tried to click on both buttons and found that excel and outlook froze up for a minute but no email was ever generated or sent. I assume something in the settings has changed due to an update as it's suddenly stopped working. I am using Office365. I noticed in outlook options under Add-ins that 'Microsoft VBA for Outlook Addin' is listed under Inactive Application Add-ins...for whatever that's worth

Screenshot - (https://ibb.co/fv2Pzx7)

Normally I would add the details for each of the files that I wish to attach on the right hand side (the directory of the file and the file name). The Job Name at the bottom right is the subject.

In VBAProject Reference I have the following boxes ticked:

- Visual Basic for Applications
- Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library

My code is quite basic I think (seeing as though even I could do it!)

```
    Sub GenerateAutoEmail3_Click()

On Error GoTo ErrHandler

' SET Outlook APPLICATION OBJECT.
Dim objOutlook As Object
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' CREATE EMAIL OBJECT.
Dim objEmail As Object
Set objEmail = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With objEmail
    .To = Range("E3")
    .Subject = Range("F3")
    .Body = "Hi " & Range("C3") & "," & Range("R13") & Range("D3") & Range("R14")

    
    .Attachments.Add Range("I3").Text
    .Attachments.Add Range("K3").Text
    .Attachments.Add Range("M3").Text
    .Attachments.Add Range("O3").Text
    
    .Send        ' DISPLAY MESSAGE.
End With

' CLEAR.
Set objEmail = Nothing:    Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

ErrHandler:
Range("G3").Value = Now
'

End Sub

(Couldn't get those last few lines in the code box!...)

Sorry if I haven't done a good job of explaining my issue or if I've rabbled on for no reason!

Thanks

Comment: What errors do you notice when running the code?

Comment: Hi and thanks for responding, no errors actually occur. The code seems to run seeing as though both excel and outlook freeze for a moment. Then it unfreezes but there are no emails in the outbox or the sent folder which normally would happen